# Float function return value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c

I am writing my object first app and i can't understand why compiler gives my errors. 
(With int codes works... )

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {


        // 1st var
        NSLog(@"Hi, %f World!", res(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f));

    }
    return 0;
}
float res (float a, float b, float c)
{
    float res=a+b+c;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message, that the compiler gives you?

Comment: Shouldn't the functin be declared before it is called for the first time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try declaring `res` before main, so that it is known to the compiler when it founds it in `main`. If you don't declare it beforehand, what happens is:

1. the compiler first encounters `res` in `main` body;
2. it makes up an "implicit declaration" for `res`, based on what it can infer from the way `res` is called inside of `main`; this implies an `int` return type, according to C conventions;
3. when the real `res` is found later on, a mismatch between the inferred signature (i.e., return type) and the real one triggers the compilation error.

To fix it:

```
float res (float a, float b, float c);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {

    // 1st var
    NSLog(@"Hi, %f World!", res(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f));
  }
  return 0;
}

float res (float a, float b, float c)
{
  float res=a+b+c;
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just forgetting to declare function, just put

```
float res (float a, float b, float c);
```

before your `int main`

hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

float res (float a, float b, float c)
{
    float res=a+b+c;
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {


        // 1st var
        NSLog(@"Hi, %f World!", res(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f));

    }
    return 0;
}
```